# How to make the setup of a system based on Postgres, Ruby and Sinatra easier?

Tags: automation

I'm working on an [open-source project](https://sivers.org/song-contest-idea). In order to start working on it, you need to set up the infrastructure as explained [here](http://altruix.cc/song-contest/how-to-set-up-song-contest-software/).

It's a tedious process.

What software (Gradle, Docker, something else) can I use to make it as easy as possible (ideally - you run one command and then everything you need to run and code on that system is installed) ? That is, what software allows me to do the steps described in the tutorial automatically?

Comment: Please explain the infrastructure in the question, people should not be forced to click the link.